# Vuejs template list array values which its keys starts with special string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I hava a vuejs template and it shows values of a nested array.
example array is:

```
myArray : [
{
  name: "abc",
  
},
{
  name123: "bcf"
},
{
  name12456: "fdf"
}
]
```

```
<template> 
<div>
{{ node.name }}
</div>
</template>
```

When I call objects of this array I can show "abc" value with {{ node.name }} but I want to show the keys starts with "name" string. So, with this way I can list all values.

Note: I just want to show keys with starts "name". There may be different keys in different arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [
        {name: "abc"}, 
        {nn00: 'rrr'},
        {name123: "bcf", ar: [{name9: 'nested1'}]}, 
        {name12456: "fdf"}, 
        {no78: "eee", ar: [{name8: 'nested2'}]}],
      res: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getValues(arr) {
      arr.forEach(a => {
        let val = Object.keys(a).filter(k => {
          if (typeof a[k] === 'object') this.getValues(a[k])
          return k.startsWith('name')
        })
        this.res.push(a[val])
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getValues(this.myArray)
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(node, i) in res" :key="i">
  {{ node }}
  </div>
</div>
```